# Rails and Nginx on different Docker containers (how share data between containers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, deployment, docker

I want to know if it's possible (or even a good practice) to run a Rails app and Nginx on different Docker containers.

My intention is to use one instance of Nginx to serve more than one application running in containers in the future.

My question is because I will have to configure Nginx to access the root path of an application running on another container (I will have on my nginx.conf: `root   /home/user/public_html/railsapp/public/;`)

How can I setup my rails docker container so the nginx container will be able to access the railsapp root path?

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether your rails application and the nginx will be two different processes or one?

In case of two, you will have rails app served somehow and nginx proxying it. Which is normal to run in two different containers.

In case you will be serving your rails app by nginx, there is no need to create a separate container. You might just add files to the container of the nginx, use volumes or data containers.